# How to download Chromium source code?

Tags: git, chromium

I'd like to download some Chromium source code. In particular, the folder described at https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/extensions/email_this_page/

How can I do that?

I can't see the clone URL. I'm not even sure whether it's a git repo.

Comment: Did you have a look at: http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code (the link you gave looks a lot like an SVN repo)

Comment: @Nobody thanks. Yes I found that doc, and found it hopelessly unclear.

Comment: Faster fetching of Chromium source code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087970/how-to-checkout-and-build-specific-chromium-tag-branch-without-download-the-full/47093174#47093174

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, you can get it from GitHub:

*The official GitHub mirror of the Chromium source*: https://github.com/chromium/chromium

Answer (score 17):

Per https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src
```

Easy peasy lemon squeezy

Comment: Please regular update your answer. As its now 2016 where we should look for.

Answer (score 2):

Cloning with `git clone` is a tad slow.  See bolded text below.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/linux_build_instructions.md#get-the-code

> Create a chromium directory for the checkout and change to it (you can call this whatever you like and put it wherever you like, as long as the full path has no spaces):
>
> ```
> $ mkdir ~/chromium && cd ~/chromium
> ```
>
> Run the fetch tool from depot_tools to check out the code and its dependencies.
>
> ```
> $ fetch --nohooks chromium
> ```
>
> If you don't want the full repo history, you can save a lot of time by adding the `--no-history` flag to fetch.
>
> Expect the command to take **30 minutes on even a fast connection, and many hours on slower ones**.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `/viewvc` from url and *clone (checkout)* with `svn checkout <url-without-viewvc>`

**Not this:**
`svn checkout http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/`

**But this:**
`svn checkout http://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/`

Answer (score 1):

The chromium page on googlesource.com has exact instructions for the same.

[Page: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src)

```sh
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src
```