# How to checkout and BUILD specific chromium tag/branch without download the FULL source code of all history?

Tags: google-chrome, build, tags, chromium, gclient

I don't want build master branch. Instead I would like to build a specific tag which the latest stable release as same as my Desktop Chrome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is probably the fastest way to fetch Chromium's source code. Suppose `59.0.3071.115` is the version of Chromium, you wish to build. You run this command:

```
git fetch https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git +refs/tags/59.0.3071.115:chromium_59.0.3071.115
```

If you don't want the history to be fetched (faster fetching of Chromium source code):

```
git fetch https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git +refs/tags/59.0.3071.115:chromium_59.0.3071.115 --depth 1
```

Now from your Chromium repo, use the following command to show a list of tags available

```
git tag
```

You have to checkout that tag by running

```
git checkout tags/59.0.3071.115
```

Then run these commands in the order listed below to pull all the third-party dependencies:

```
gclient sync
gclient sync --with_branch_heads
gclient runhooks
```

You can find the dev, beta, canary, latest and stable version info of Chromium from this page: https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/schedule

Now, you should be able to build Chromium. Let me know, if it works

Comment: Other answers have you also do a `git checkout`. Can you explain why you only have to do a `fetch` and then `gclient sync`?

Comment: @WiteCastle You have to checkout that tag by running ``git checkout tags/59.0.3071.115``. Use ``git tag`` to show a list of tags available. That fetch command will just fetch the last commit of that branch, so it won't fetch the whole history. ``gclient sync`` will download the third party dependencies needed for Chromium to compile

Comment: @Asesh Thank you so much. Your knowledge fill the last part of the picture. I finally automate the build of headless chrome and published on Docker HUB.  https://hub.docker.com/r/microbox/chromium-headless

Comment: If using `--depth` flag with `git fetch`, make sure to use `--depth 4` or a reasonable number so that at least one commit in the history has `Cr-Commit-Position:` in the commit message. This metadata is necessary for the hooks (and build) to run successfully.