# Compile older version of Chromium without AutoUpdating

Tags: linux, git, compilation, chromium, ninja

I try to compile an older version of chromium on Ubuntu by checking out an older version as described here: [Checking out a release branch](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches), but it then keeps staying on a higher version of Chromium.

How do I prevent this, so I can actually compile the older version of Chromium?

The commands I used were:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git

export PATH="$PATH:${HOME}/depot_tools"
mkdir ~/chromium && cd ~/chromium
fetch chromium
cd src
./build/install-build-deps.sh
gclient runhooks

git checkout -b tags/34.0.1847.9
gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags
cat chrome/VERSION

gn gen out/Default
autoninja -C out/Default chrome
out/Default/chrome
```

And it shows Chromium 75 at 'cat chrome/VERSION', every single time instead of branch version 34.0.1847.9.

Comment: The compiling process looks good to me. After you checkout this tag ``34.0.1847.9``, can you goto ``chrome`` folder and open ``VERSION`` file to verify that you have checked out the right version?

Comment: @Asesh Strange enough version is not changed from 75 to 34, after switching to version 34 branch:
git checkout -b tags/34.0.1847.9
gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags
cat chrome/VERSION still says MAJOR=75.

Comment: Looks like there's probably something wrong with your repo. That should not happen. You might want to clean up that repo and try again.

Comment: @Asesh Chromium guy said "It's not following the syntax exactly for the git checkout -b." What's wrong with the syntax? How to fix the commands that are used?

Comment: You should checkout this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087970/how-to-checkout-and-build-specific-chromium-tag-branch-without-download-the-full/47093174?noredirect=1#comment96752257_47093174 Should be helpful to you