# Can someone give me a ZIP file with Chromiums source code for Mac with the Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, browser, chromium

I've been trying to get chromiums source code for macOS for about 1 month. I've been struggling so much trying to get the code. I followed the [instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/mac_build_instructions.md) carefully but nothing ever works. I tried installing on several macs but I get errors. Since nothing works for me, can you please give me a link with chromium source code for mac with the Xcode project.

Comment: It will be too big, uncompressed size is around 16.x GB. If you don't want the full history then the size of that repo will be comparatively small. Use this technique for doing so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087970/how-to-checkout-and-build-specific-chromium-tag-branch-without-download-the-full/47093174#47093174

Comment: I get an error saying no such `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: That's because you have not initialized git in that directory

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: So I just clone this `git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src` For the source code?