# How to determine current chromium source stable version?

Tags: chromium

I want to use the Chromium source to build a stable browser version. But I do not understand how to determine stable chromium source versions because it is released several times to day, and releases have no **stable** or **intermediate** marks.
By stable version, I mean the version that is tested by some QA group and is marked as ready for production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The daily builds that you are referring to are canary builds which are for development purposes only. If you want to check out a stable build from the Chromium repo then you need to find out the **stable version**.

For that you can go to https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/ and find out the current/previous stable version of Chromium/Chrome. Use `channel` and `current_version` columns as a reference.

Chromium uses tags to represent a specific version. So, for example, if the current stable version is `89.0.4389.90`, execute the following git commands from your Chromium repo:

Fetch the remote tags:

```
git fetch --tags
```

List all the available tags (Optional):

```
git tag
```

Checkout the specified tag:

```
git checkout tags/89.0.4389.90
```

After checking out a specific tag, follow the commands here to pull third-party deps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087970/how-to-checkout-and-build-specific-chromium-tag-branch-without-download-the-full/47093174#47093174)