# How to obtain a particular version of Chromium source code?

Tags: git, chromium, gclient

I need to get the source code of [Chromium 88](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/tags/88.0.4324.86). However, officially proposed `$ fetch chromium` in `depot_tools` automatically downloads source files from the master branch and does not allow to choose a particular version. Is there a possibility to get (and successfully compile using `depot_tools ninja`) the source code of Chromium 88, while Chromium 92 is the most recent build?

Answer (score 3):

The master branch of Chromium is not a stable version. Chromium versions are represented by tags. After fetching Chromium source code, you will have to follow the following steps:

From `src` directory:

Fetch all the tags:

```
git fetch --tags
```

Checkout the version you want:

```
git checkout tags/88.0.4324.86
```

Pull third-party deps:

```
gclient sync
```

Now, you should be able to compile Chromium:

```
gn gen out\YourBuildFolder
ninja -C out\YourBuildFolder
```

I have posted more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087970/how-to-checkout-and-build-specific-chromium-tag-branch-without-download-the-full/47093174#47093174)

Answer (score 1):

That repo is mirrored in GitHub, where you can grab many branches and tags.

https://github.com/chromium/chromium

Once you clone the repo, you can checkout versions by tag (build number).

```
git checkout 92.0.4482.3
```

Comment: Looks like he followed the official direction for getting started with Chromium source, so I have posted the relevant details as another answer